# Finding matrix from plane in kernal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Give an example of a matrix A such that $\ker(A)$ is the plane $2x − y + 3z = 0$.

I am not sure where to start, as I know that the $\ker(A)$ is the matrix of the plane, but I don't know how to go backwards from it. Would I need to assume that there's a free variable in the rref(A) and assume it was pulled out of the equation of the plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$A\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}=0$$ implies $$2x-y+3z=0$$

Comment: Ahhhh, I was totally overthinking it. Thanks!

Comment: @150005388 You are welcome.

Comment: Why do you need anything beyond the first row? There’s nothing in the question that constrains the size of the matrix.

Comment: @amd You are right. I am just used to considering linear transformations in $n$-dimensional vector space $V$: $V\to V$, so my matrix is a square matrix.